S3 Browser DELETE Bucket objects
I'm using S3 Browser to storage some data, and I'm trying to delete a specific group of objects withing a bucket. I have tried to use policies but it seems it's not the right option, and I'm trying t implement a lifecycle rule, but I'm always getting this XML error. Does anybody have an idea of how I could solve this?
ERROR:

Unable to perform requested action:
-----------------------------------------------------------
Error occurred during Applying lifecycle rules for 
rt-dev-3-maps MalformedXML
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server Response:
MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well formed or
did not validate against our published schema. Expecting a 
namespace for element LifecycleConfiguration, line 2
-----------------------------------------------------------
See Event log for more details. If you think you've found a 
bug, please use Tools->Diagnostics to send the report.

I was trying to create a bucket policy to delete all my objects whose driveId = 60 (or any other number I introduce). I read it's not possible to do such thing with policies, since the "grouping" or "filtering" feature is not supported. I read about lifecycles, and I think that could be the right approach, but when trying to configure one in my S3 Browser, I'm always getting this XML error.
You can reproduce this by following these steps:

Open S3 Browser, and connect it to some amazon account OR (what I did) create a Tebi account, and add some buckets and some data into them.
Create a key, and add this bucket list (with the created keys) into S3 Browser.
When the bucket is loaded, right click on it --> Lifecycle Configuration -->Add
The exact data I had was:

Prefix: 60-
In actions for current and non current versions --> Permamently delete files: 1
In abort uploads: 7


Add new rule --> Save

After following this steps, if I'm not having a local issue, you should be able to reproduce the error.
